# Concat two columns values of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
     Name  Age
0    Alex   10
1     Bob   12
2  Clarke   13
```

The dataframe is created as:

```
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
```

I want to perform string concatenation of the two columns as:

```
     Name      Age
0    10 Alex   10 
1    12 Bob    12 
2    13 Clarke 13
```

I tried using `df["Name"] = df["Age"]+" "+df["Name"]`, which resulted in the below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py",
> line 65, in new_method
> return method(self, other)   File "/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/**init**.py",
> line 343, in wrapper
> result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)   File "/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py",
> line 189, in arithmetic_op
> res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)   File "/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py",
> line 149, in na_arithmetic_op
> result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)   File "/anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py",
> line 111, in masked_arith_op
> result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], y) numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a
> loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) ->
> dtype('<U21')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since `Age` is an `int` column, you need to cast it to `str` using `astype`

```
In [2511]: df['Name'] = df["Age"].astype(str) + " " + df["Name"]

In [2511]: df['Name']
Out[2511]: 
0      10 Alex
1       12 Bob
2    13 Clarke
```

Answer (score 4):

#### [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

```
df['Name'] = df['Age'].astype(str).str.cat(df['Name'], sep=' ')

        Name  Age
0    10 Alex   10
1     12 Bob   12
2  13 Clarke   13
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
df['Name'] = df['Age'].map(str) + ' ' + df['Name']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`df['Name']=df['Age'].apply(lambda x :str(x)) + ' ' + df['Name']`

Answer (score 1):

We can use the apply function to cast the dataframe "age" column to string from int and then concatenate it to the "name" column using the "+" operator.

**df["name"] = df["age"].apply(str) + " " + df["name"]**

**df["name"]**

The output will look something like this

```
0      10 Alex
1      12 Bob
2      13 Clarke
```